# Why the Split function has two array?

Tags: c#

When i program with C#,using Split function:

```
string[] singleStr=str.Split(';');
```

the str is `column111.dwg&186&0;`

Why the `singleStr.Length=2`? Why give a array althrough the array is null?

Comment: What is `desStr`? I don't see it.

Comment: The *array* is *null*? Really? If so, how can you access `Length`?

Comment: `Split` assumes there is a `';'` _between_ all the parts, as in `aaa;bb;cccc;dddd`. So if there are *x* semicolons in the input, the resulting array will have *x* + 1 entries. In particular the resulting array always has at least one entry. If instead the format is `aaa;bb;cccc;dddd;`, i.e. there is a `';'` _after_ each part, including one after the final part, you want an array of length *x* where *x* is the number of semicolons. To achieve that (whether there are any empty parts or not), create a new array from the output from `Split` by discarding the last entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `desStr` looks like but sounds like you need to use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.StringSplitOptions.aspx)

> The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty
>   string

```
string str = "column111.dwg&186&0;";
string[] singleStr = str.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var item in singleStr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be only;

```
column111.dwg&186&0
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/eaOiUl)</kbd>

If we don't use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` in this case, `singleStr` array has 2 items; `column111.dwg&186&0` and `""`

Comment: +1 Totally impressed by the thing that compiles and execute code in a browser

Comment: No, when we don't use `RemoveEmptyEntries`, the resulting array has entries `"column111.dwg&186&0"` and `""`. No `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to have empty entries, use this construction:

```
string[] singleStr=str.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's correct to have two items in your array as you do have a semicolon in your string.

One of the prototypes of Split method allow you to set the `SplitStringOptions` to `RemoveEmptyEntries`

Eg:

```
var parts = yourString.Split( new []{';'}, SplitStringOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string[] singleStr=str.Split(new[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

it will remove `null`'s and empty strings like whitespaces and others

Answer to your question:
array length is 2 because Split sees: `column111.dwg&186&0;` and do split on `;` and gets:

`column111.dwg&186&0` and after `;` it has `null` string only

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to ignore empty entries, try using

[String.Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this string
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified Unicode character array.
>   **A parameter specifies whether to return empty array elements.**

[StringSplitOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> RemoveEmptyEntries:
>
> The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty
>   string

Answer (score 1):

This is because it splits the string everywhere it finds a ";" in the string and that results in an empty entry because your ";" is at the end of the string.

You can use following call to remove emtpy entries:

```
str.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```